# rails 3 - I18n::InvalidLocaleData

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I am making my website multilanguage using [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n?view=asciicast)

But at the very beginning I get an error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData in Users#index

Showing .../app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #1 raised:

can not load translations from .../config/locales/en.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, t('users.index.title.site_title')) %>
<h1><%= t 'users.index.title.head' %></h1>

<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag (t 'users.index.search_form.search'), :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
    users:
        index:
            title:
                site_title: "Users"
                head: "Users"
            search_form:
                search: "Search"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locale data should be indented two spaces, not four, so correct version is:

```
en:
  users:
    index:
      title:
        site_title: "Users"
        head: "Users"
      search_form:
        search: "Search"
```

Also, check if you're using spaces or tabs, latter will cause troubles.

Comment: What is the output of `YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/en.yml'))` command? (Of course in your rails console)

Comment: `Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1` line 5 is users:

Comment: You've got probably `tab` there instead of `space`s. Try pasting whole file to 'http://yamllint.com/', parsing it and pasting back to `en.yml`.

Comment: I already had done it, now I did it again. Restart the server. Nothing changed.

Comment: I made it! There was a `tr.yml` which I don't call anywhere. I deleted its content and now `en.yml` is working well. Thanks for your support!

Comment: That's interesting, I wonder why Rails were pointing to wrong file, anyway, glad you resolved it.

Comment: I don't think it was pointing to `tr.yml`, I think it just try to load all `.yml` files at the beginning

Comment: Yep, but during loading files are probably parsed so throwing error during that process shouldn't be impossible, I will dig into it after work.